# bash script - logrotate output rename

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, logrotate

When executing `logrotate` it shows following:

```
error: error creating output file /var/log/remote/172.29.202.29/contrail-vrouter-agent.log.1: File exists
error: error creating output file /var/log/remote/172.29.207.139/swift-object-server.log.1: File exists
...
```

There are something like 1000 of these exisiting `log.1` files. I would like to rename them all to `***log.2`   so I can re-run `logrotate` successfully.

How do I do this?

Comment: logrotate should name the files incrementally, so it looks like your problem is with your logrotate setup. Can you clarify whether you just want a one-time fix for this in that you just want to rename all files from `*log.1` to `*log.2` please? Alternatively, if you want help with your logrotate setup, it would be useful to see your config

Comment: Please confirm that you don't also have `*.log.1.gz` files (e.g. `contrail-vrouter-agent.log.1` and `contrail-vrouter-agent.log.1.gz`). This is a common reason for `logrotate` not being able to cycle log files automatically.

Comment: You could add your logrotate config file for this file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a one-time fix, this should do the trick:

```
find /var/log/remote/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -name *.log.1 | sed -e 's/log\.1/log\./g'  | xargs -i mv {}1 {}2
```

However please note that this will rename *ALL*  `*.log.1` files in `/var/log/remote/*/`

So if there are some directories you want to skip in `/var/log/remote/`, you should use the `-not -path <path>` option after find (see [this answer in another thread for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13460641/5019164))